# Is is possible to create a for-of loop without a variable?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
const hasAny = xs => {
  for (const x of xs) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

[eslint](/questions/tagged/eslint) will complain that `x` is not used, and indeed it isn't.

Can I write a for-of loop that does not declare any variables?

Comment: Maybe for what you need with an `return xs.length > 0` is enough for you.

Comment: @JesúsMagallón - Not all iterables have a `length` property.

Comment: Would eslint be happy if you named the variable `_`?

Comment: @Bergi sadly this isn't ML

Comment: @sdgfsdh looks like `{ "varsIgnorePattern": "^_" }` should be the default eslint configuration

Comment: @sdgfsdh It's an ESLint config, not a language issue.

Comment: @Walfrat - The `for-of` shown tests exactly this: That `xs` is iterable (error thrown otherwise) and its iterator returns at least one value (so not "empty" by whatever definition of "empty" that iterable applies).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I am just checking if this is exact the behaviour that the OP want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you can't, not in the general case.¹ You can use the iterator² directly, though:

```
const hasAny = xs => !xs[Symbol.iterator]().next().done;
```

Or if you want to ensure you proactively release any resources the iterator holds (rather than waiting for them to be released automatically — think DB connection in a generator function or similar), proactively call `return` on it if it provides a `return` (not all do) like `for-of` does under the covers:

```
const hasAny = xs => {
    const it = xs[Symbol.iterator]();
    const result = !it.next().done;
    if (it.return) it.return();
    return result;
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const hasAny = xs => !xs[Symbol.iterator]().next().done;

console.log(hasAny([]));  // false
console.log(hasAny([1])); // true
```

---

¹ If you know for sure the iterator's first value won't be `null` or `undefined`, you can do [this destructuring trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52667765/157247).

² *For any who don't happen to know, `for-of` uses an iterator under the covers.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use destructuring with an empty object:

```
const hasAny = xs => {
  for (const {} of xs) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

UPDATE: This does not work when the list contains `undefined`.

Comment: the real beauty of javascript :)

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work for anything that is not an iterable of iterables. Try `hasAny([1])`

Comment: Now it fails if the iterable's first value is `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

According to ESLint issue [#2173](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2173), you can set a comment to ignore the unused variable. For that, use the following code:

```
var some_unused_variable; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
```

A community member of ESLint also states:

> We now have a [`varsIgnorePattern`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#varsignorepattern) option available for this use case (best suited for ignoring specific unused variable names or patterns across all your files).

And documentation states:

> The varsIgnorePattern option specifies exceptions not to check for usage: variables whose names match a regexp pattern. For example, variables whose names contain ignored or Ignored.
>
> Examples of correct code for the { "varsIgnorePattern": "[iI]gnored" } option:
>
> ```
> /*eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "varsIgnorePattern": "[iI]gnored" }]*/
>
> var firstVarIgnored = 1;
> var secondVar = 2;
> console.log(secondVar);
> ```

Comment: This is true, but it's not an answer to the question. The question doesn't ask how to make ESLint stop complaining. It asks if you can avoid declaring a variable in a `for-of` loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder *Because ESLint complains*, they look for a workaround, which is to eliminate the variable. Kind of a XY problem, in this case the Y problem happens to be interesting.

Comment: Generally, the better approach in such a case is to post a new question that asks about the underlying problem ("how do I shut up ESLint in this case?"), self-answer it (with something that answers *that* question), and post a link over on the inspiring question along the lines of "you probably want to check out ..." with a link to the new question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `forEach` method instead:

```
const hasAny = xs => {
    xs.forEach(() => {
        return true;
    })

    return false;
};
```